# How to load webpage in an iframe on click of a link of another iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have two iframes (say 1 & 2) in a webpage. In the iframe1, I have a hyperlink on click of which, I want to load another webpage in the iframe2.

Can you please tell me whether loading a page from one iframe to another is possible and if so, please help in doing it. Thanks.

Note: all the web pages that I am considering here are in same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the name attribute on your iframes

then use target on your links

```
<iframe name='mydetails' src='someSrc.html'></iframe>
```

in your other iframe

```
<a href='details.html target='mydetails'>My details</a>
```